# timeout when waiting for 3rd party check iframe message keycloak error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, keycloak, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a big problem with HTTPS and Keycloak. In my configuration I have an ec2 inside private subnet on AWS, with ALB in front of it. Also, I have configured a record dns to hide the private ip of my ec2.

So, I have created two files .pem (cert.pem and key.pem) with OpenSSL and I don't have any problem with this but when I try to access my keycloak with "https://mydomainrecordns:443" I have an error but when I type https://my-private-ip:443 I can see the main page of keycloak but when I click on administration console I'm stuck with a spinning and the error "timeout when waiting for 3rd party check iframe message" and I don't know how to solve.

My files.pem are configured with the domain name of my hosted zone where my record dns is created(a private hosted zone FYI)

I have tried to configure properly the hostname with mydomain.it record dns and googled a lot on the web but also in development mode I can't access my admin console and I don't know how to solve. I have tried also to analyze proxy or other settings of my ALB that are the following

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9iRp.png)

My target groups with private ip (I have to register a target group for my record dns?)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThBFt.png)

This is my docker file configuration

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest as builder


ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true 
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true


WORKDIR /opt/keycloak

COPY cert.pem /opt/keycloak/cert.pem 
COPY key.pem /opt/keycloak/key.pem


RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest 
ENV KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE=/opt/keycloak/cert.pem 
ENV KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE=/opt/keycloak/key.pem

COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/
```

Any suggestion is very appreciate

I hope all my explanation was clear and thanks in advance

Comment: I have solded by setting --proxy=edge